# button event with validation and actions

Tags: c#, events, button

I need help with the Check button. After a user adds all the 42 numbers in the textbox and enter a number from 0-9 in the "Enter number" area and clicks on the start button, next what he should do is run through the array of labels with the red label or lblCovece and he should collect the same values like the number enters before. And after he clicks on the Check button, the programme should first validate if the value that is selected with the red label is the same as the number entered. If is valid the label should turn green and  than the result should appear in the label lblResultE(the result for example should be like this: if the number entered is 2, the result it is 2+2+2...)and if is not valid in the lblResultE we take out 10 points. That's what i did by now with some help.:) thank you.

```
  namespace Seminarska
   {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
    private Label l,l2,lblCovece,l4,lblResultE;
    private Button bUp, bRight, bLeft, bDown, bCheck,bStart, bReset;
    private TextBox txtVnes, txtGoal;
    private Label[] pole;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        l2 = new Label();
        l2.Text = " Enter one number";
        l2.Location = new Point(230, 200);
        l2.AutoSize = true;
        l4 = new Label();
        l4.Text = "Score";
        l4.Location = new Point(240, 260);
        l4.AutoSize = true;
        lblResultE = new Label();
        lblResultE.Location = new Point(350, 260);
        lblResultE.AutoSize = true;
        bLeft = new Button();
        bLeft.Location = new Point(0, 250);
        bLeft.Width=75;
        bLeft.Height = 25;
        bLeft.Text = "LEFT";
        bCheck = new Button();
        bCheck.Location = new Point(75, 250);
        bCheck.Width = 75;
        bCheck.Height = 25;
        bCheck.Text = "Check";
        bRight = new Button();
        bRight.Location = new Point(150, 250);
        bRight.Width = 75;
        bRight.Height = 25;
        bRight.Text = "RIGHT";
        bUp = new Button();
        bUp.Location = new Point(75, 220);
        bUp.Width = 75;
        bUp.Height = 25;
        bUp.Text = "UP";
        bDown = new Button();
        bDown.Location = new Point(75, 280);
        bDown.Width = 75;
        bDown.Height = 25;
        bDown.Text = "DOWN";
        bStart = new Button();
        bStart.Location = new Point(240, 165);
        bStart.Width = 75;
        bStart.Height = 25;
        bStart.Text = "START";
        bReset = new Button();
        bReset.Location = new Point(320, 165);
        bReset.Width = 75;
        bReset.Height = 25;
        bReset.Text = "RESET";
        txtVnes = new TextBox();
        txtVnes.Location = new Point(240, 10);
        txtVnes.Width = 160;
        txtVnes.Height = 130;
        txtVnes.Multiline = true;
        txtGoal = new TextBox();
        txtGoal.Width = 75;
        txtGoal.Height = 25;
        txtGoal.Location = new Point(330, 200);
        lblCovece = new Label();
        lblCovece.Location = new Point(160,165);
        lblCovece.Width = 20;
        lblCovece.Height = 20;
        lblCovece.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        lblCovece.Text = "O";
        lblCovece.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
        int a = 0;
        pole = new Label[42];
        this.Controls.Add(lblCovece); 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
            {                     
                l = new Label();
                l.Name = "label" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();                    
                l.Text = "Z";
                l.Width = 20;
                l.Height = 20;
                l.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                l.Parent = this;                     
                l.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 149, 237);                    
                l.Location = new Point(10 + (j - 1) * 25, 15 + (i - 1) * 25);
                pole[a] = l;                  
                this.Controls.Add(l);                    
                a++;  
            }
        }

        this.Width = 460;
        this.Height = 380;           
        this.Controls.Add(l2);       
        this.Controls.Add(l4);
        this.Controls.Add(lblResultE);
        this.Controls.Add(lblTimeE);            
        this.Controls.Add(bStart);
        this.Controls.Add(bReset);
        this.Controls.Add(txtGoal);
        this.Controls.Add(txtVnes);
        this.Controls.Add(bUp);
        this.Controls.Add(bLeft);
        this.Controls.Add(bRight);
        this.Controls.Add(bDown);
        this.Controls.Add(bCheck);

        bStart.Click+=new EventHandler(bStart_Click);
        bUp.Click+=new EventHandler(bUp_Click);
        bDown.Click+=new EventHandler(bDown_Click);
        bLeft.Click+=new EventHandler(bLeft_Click);
        bRight.Click+=new EventHandler(bRight_Click);
        bCheck.Click+=new EventHandler(bZemaj_Click);
        bReset.Click+=new EventHandler(bReset_Click);
    }

    private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Str = txtGoal.Text.Trim();
        int Num;
        bool isNum = int.TryParse(Str, out Num);
        if (isNum && Str.Length == 1)
        {
            string[] ts = txtVnes.Text.Split(
                       new string[] { "\r\n" },  
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int row = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ts.Length && row < 6; i++)
            {
                if (LineIsValid(ts[i]))
                {
                    for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
                    {
                        pole[row * 7 + col].Text = ts[i][2 * col].ToString();

                    }
                    row++;
                }
            }
            for (; row < 6; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
                {
                    pole[row * 7 + col].Text = "Z";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input");

        }
    }

     private static Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\s)*(\d ){6}\d(\s)*$");

     private static bool LineIsValid(string line)
    {
    return regex.IsMatch(line);

     }

    private void bReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           txtVnes.Clear();
            string[] ts = txtVnes.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" },  
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int row = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ts.Length && row < 6; i++)
            {

                    for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
                    {
                        pole[row * 7 + col].Text = "Z";
                        pole[row * 7 + col].BackColor=Color.FromArgb(100, 149, 237);
                    }
                    row++;

            }


            for (; row < 6; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
                {
                    pole[row * 7 + col].Text = "Z";
                    pole[row * 7 + col].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 149, 237);
                }
            }

           txtGoal.Clear();
           lblCovece.Location=new Point(160,165);

    }


    private void bUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         lblCovece.Location = new Point(lblCovece.Location.X, lblCovece.Location.Y -      
             25);

    }

    private void bDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCovece.Location = new Point(lblCovece.Location.X, lblCovece.Location.Y + 
           25);
    }

    private void bLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCovece.Location = new Point(lblCovece.Location.X - 25,              
         lblCovece.Location.Y);
    }
    private void bRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCovece.Location = new Point(lblCovece.Location.X + 25,  
            lblCovece.Location.Y);
    }
    private void bCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }




     }
  }
```

Comment: It is unclear what or where the problem is. Can you indicate in what line something is wrong (and then maybe remove the other stuff that doesn't contribute). In general this is not a debugging website.

Comment: It might just be me but could you rephrase your question. What is it you are exactly asking?

Comment: Well actually a haven't write anything, that's the problem. I don't know how to write the part in the bCheck_Click event. And I explained above what the Check button should do.

Comment: When the values from the txtVnes are copied in the array of labels, the user with the buttons Up,Left, Right and Down, should move the label lblCovece(the red label), and should look for the same value he entered before in the txtGoal.

Comment: And after he clicks on the button Check,if the lblCovece is overlapping a label from the array of labels with the same values as the value entered in the txtGoal, the result which it must be shown in the lblResultE label, should increase for the value that is enterd and collected.

Comment: I understand that you create the 7 x 6 labels of the matrix programmatically. However, why are you adding the other controls programmatically as well instead of working with the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an int score;

```
private void bCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool found = false;
            foreach (Label l in pole)
            {
                if (l.Location == lblCovece.Location && l.Text == txtGoal.Text)
                {
                    l.BackColor = Color.Green;

                    score += int.Parse(l.Text);
                    lblResultE.Text = score.ToString();
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                score -= 10;
                lblResultE.Text = score.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes that's my point,but how can I increase the score? for example if I enter 2, and run through the array and collect all the 2, the result it should be 2+2+2..., it depends how many 2 i will collect

Comment: It doesn't work, it says cannot convert type int to string in this line lblResultE.Text=score;. I also add int score;

Comment: lblResultE.Text = score.ToString();

Comment: OK, but it gives me very big score(negative):-403...-736...-1069...(that happens wheh I enter 7).

Answer (score 1):

What makes your programm complicated and difficult to understand, is that you mix game logic with display logic.

I suggest you to redesign your game. It could look something like this:

```
public enum State
{
    Empty,   // Displays "Z"
    Neutral, // Blue 
    Good,    // Green 
    Bad      // Red
}

public class Square
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public const int Width = 7, Height = 6;

    public Game()
    {
        Board = new Square[Width, Height];
    }

    public event EventHandler GameChanged;

    public Square[,] Board { get; private set; }

    public int CurrentX { get; private set; }
    public int CurrentY { get; private set; }

    public void Reset()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++) {
                Board[x, y].State = State.Empty;  // Always displayed in blue as "Z"
            }
        }
        OnGameChanged();
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        if (CurrentX > 0) {
            CurrentX--;
            OnGameChanged();
        }
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
        if (CurrentX < Width - 1) {
            CurrentX++;
            OnGameChanged();
        }
    }

    // and so on

    private void OnGameChanged()
    {
        EventHandler eh = GameChanged;
        if (eh != null) {
            eh(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

In the form I would define `pole` to be a matrix as well (like the board). I show only a few relevant parts of the form code, to give you an idea of what I mean:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Game game;
    private Label[,] pole;

    public Form1()
    {
        game = new Game();
        game.GameChanged += new EventHandler(Game_GameChanged);

        pole = new Label[Game.Width, Game.Height];

        // Intialize pole.
        // ...
    }

    void Game_GameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Game.Width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < Game.Height; y++) {
                Square square = game.Board[x, y];
                Label label = pole[x,y];
                switch (square.State) {
                    case State.Empty:
                        label.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                        label.Text = "Z";
                        break;
                    case State.Neutral:
                        label.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                        label.Text = square.Number.ToString();
                        break;
                    case State.Good:
                        label.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        label.Text = square.Number.ToString();
                        break;
                    case State.Bad:
                        label.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        label.Text = square.Number.ToString();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Place lblCovece according to game.CurrentX and game.CurrentY
        // ...
    }

    private void bReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        game.Reset();
    }

    private void bLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        game.MoveLeft();
    }

    private void bRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        game.MoveRight();
    }
}
```

Note how the Game class tells the form when changes happen through the event `GameChanged`. The form then updates the game display. In the game class, you can now concentrate on the game logic and do not have to deal with buttons and labels. You can also work with logical coordinates in the range [0..6] and [0..5] of the game board. This is easier than working with pixels. You delegate all the pixel calculations to the form.

My example is not complete, but when you try to implement it, you will see that it will be much easier to think about how the logic of the game should work.

Comment: Half of it i understand it,but in the other half I got lost :) I think I'm going to continue with the previous code.Thanks